# Is it possible to modify the body of triggers and classes in a Salesforce Production instance?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

If i have a number of triggers and classes registered in Salesforce Production instance from my SandBox.
If the registered triggers / classes have been modified is it possible to update the trigger in Production without having to rerun the tests and get the 75% pass rate because I already have ?

At the moment if I have registered triggers / classes in Production  and I have my app pointing to that Production instance,if the trigger has been modified because i dont know what the user has changed I delete the trigger or class and try to register , but because it Production it wont let me .
Is there a way I can do this or do I have to update in SandBox and then push to Production every time ?

Comment: What do you mean registered? What user? Your question could use some more clarification. Generally, though, you cannot deploy a trigger or class in a production environment. You would have to send it from Sandbox. If memory serves, you can't delete from prod either so I am not sure what scenario you find yourself in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the registered triggers / classes have been modified is it possible to update the trigger in Production without having to rerun the tests and get the 75% pass rate because I already have ?

No. Your sandbox and production org are different environments, and the code coverage obtained in sandbox may not reflect the coverage available in production.

Each time you modify Apex code in a sandbox environment, you must perform a deployment to production, including running Apex tests. There is no way around that requirement.

Your question is hard to follow due to some non-standard terminology, but it sounds like you are badly in need of a defined change control process, preferably using source control as the source of truth.